# How to make a Tile class and add it to a JFrame?

Tags: java

So I have a tile class:

public class Tile extends JLabel{

```
private char _c;
private static char randomChar;

public Tile(char c, Color background) {
    super();
    setBackground(background);
    setOpaque(true);
    _c = c;

}

public static char randomLetter() {
    Random r = new Random();
    randomChar = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(25));
    return randomChar;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tile tile = new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.BLUE);
    Tile tile1 = new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.RED);
    Tile tile2 = new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.GREEN);
    Tile tile3 = new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.YELLOW);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    frame.setSize(500, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(tile);
    frame.add(tile1);
    frame.add(tile2);
    frame.add(tile3);

    System.out.println(Tile.randomLetter());
```

It should have a letter and a color. I'm trying to create a 4 by 1 grid of these tiles in a `JFrame`. How would I do that?

Supposedly I need to have another class for example a Model class to keep making these tiles instead of manually. How would I do that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `JLabel`:

```
JLabel blueLabel = new JLabel("a");
blueLabel.setOpaque(true);
blueLabel.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
```

Then you can use a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` and add the labels to the panel:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 0) );
panel.add(blueLabel);
panel.add(redLabel);
panel.add(...);
```

Edit:

```
public class Tile extends JLabel
{
    public Tile(String letter, Color background)
    {
        super(letter);
        setBackground( background );
        setOpaque( false );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi that could work, however my instructions require me to define my own Tile class that has a letter

Comment: @Kisuna97 So?  Extend from a `JLabel` and provide functionality so it can be configured from a `Tile`

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I go about that? Im new to java and i understand how to extend it.. but idk how to create a tile class using JLabels

Comment: Hi thats what did after your example. I still can't get a tile to appear in a frame. Would it better help you if I just post my instructions here? The links are as follows                                                                                     1: https://gyazo.com/feab6218bf4613e93e20015aee9d3dab                        2: https://gyazo.com/c6e9541aaba19f7c4b35510642741f96                          3: https://gyazo.com/07ab146a6aae40f5a469f474010706df                                                                    @camickr

Comment: @Kisuna97,  `I still can't get a tile to appear in a frame` start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Download the demo code and test it. Then change one of the JLabels to use the Tile class from above.

Comment: @camickr https://gyazo.com/f849ac0736685af5537b45c3b0983c1b                                     Thats what i got now. the strings of the tile appears but no color. Can i make my tiles type char? instead of type string? Because for my game i need the char or letters of the tiles to change randomly

Comment: @Kisuna97, `but no color` - Sorry that was a typo. That should be `setOpaque(true)`. Did you read the API to see what that method does? Take the time to understand the suggestions given, so you can catch a typo. `Can i make my tiles type char?` Why. Whats wrong using a String with a single character. Then you also have the option to use multiple characters. `i need the char or letters of the tiles to change randomly` - you just use the `setText()` method of the Tile class to change the text.

Comment: Also, post the actual code in your question, not a picture of the code.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for your help i really appreciate it . The visual part works fine now. I also need the type to be char because im using a random char generated (in the code above). So i want the tiles to have random characters randomly generated everytime I run the code for now. After i get that to work i have to get the specific tile to be removed if i type that letter on my keyboard

Comment: @Kisuna97, `to have random characters randomly generated`, - you can randomly generate a one character string just as easily. You are making this way too complicated.

Comment: @camickr i know using a string would be much simpler but I'm required to use char for my projectt

Comment: @Kisuna97, then you don't understand what your project is about. A JLabel can only paint a String. So that means you can't use a JLabel so all advice given in this posting will not help you. OR you can generate a character and pass it in the constructor to your Tile object and then convert the character to a String so that you can set the text of the label. Only you know the requirements. So either you have to start over or do what I suggested. I can't help any more.

Comment: @Kisuna97, to clarify my statement. Swing uses a `Graphics` object to do painting. So JLabel, JButton, JTable etc all use this Graphics object. Take a look at the API and you will see that there is no `drawCharacter(...)` method, only a `drawstring(...)` method. So your requirement may be to generate a random character, but if you every want to paint this character you need to convert it so a String. So once you convert it to a String you can then use a JLabel.