# How to add my Arraylist of Tile objects to a JPanel?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this. I have created a tile class to associate with my tile objects, but I'm unsure of how to add my `ArrayList` of tile objects to my JPanel.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class First implements Runnable{

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

JFrame fr = new JFrame("Frame");
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.setSize(300,700);

JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
p.setVisible(true);
fr.add(p);
JLabel blue = new JLabel("a");
//blue.setOpaque(true);
//blue.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
p.add(blue);
JLabel red = new JLabel("b");
//red.setOpaque(true);
//red.setBackground( Color.RED);
p.add(red);
JLabel green = new JLabel("c");
//green.setOpaque(true);
//green.setBackground( Color.GREEN);
p.add(green);
JLabel orange = new JLabel("d");
orange.setOpaque(true);
orange.setBackground( Color.ORANGE);
p.add(orange);
    char a = 0;
    char b = 0;
    char c = 0;
    char d = 0;

    Tile ta = new Tile(a);
    Tile tb = new Tile(b);
    Tile tc = new Tile(c);
    Tile td = new Tile(d);

    //p.(ta);

    ArrayList<Tile>tile = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    tile.add(ta);
    tile.add(tb);
    tile.add(tc);
    tile.add(td);



    for(Tile s: tile){
        System.out.println("Printed:"+s);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: An ArrayList isn't something that itself is an argument in a JPanel.add() method. It is not a component. But it can hold components that get displayed. Maybe you need to take another look at the original question, as asking to literally display an ArrayList doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why don't you talk to the friends in your class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704360/how-to-make-a-tile-class-and-add-it-to-a-jframe

Comment: @camickr I'm trying to understand the code without messing it up too much. I added my characters: char a, char b, etc. to my Panel and I know that because they're not strings they won't actually display something. What I want to understand is how would go about adding my tile objects to my JPanel and have it display properly.

Comment: @Phil Freihofner I understand that it doesn't make any sense. I'm really new to this and I'm trying to wrap my mind around the concepts of coding in java. I'm really not sure what to do with the array list as it's just sitting in my code holding my four tile objects.

Comment: @JahvieMars, and the link I provided you gives an answer. Like you say a String is not a Component so you can't add it to a panel, so you need to change your code. Which means you have to "mess it up" a bit to get it working. You can't force it work the way you coded it just because you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if this is what you are asking. But if you want to display the *contents* of an ArrayList on a JPanel, you can just iterate through it.

```
for (Tile t:tile) p.add(t);
```

This assumes that Tile is an extension of Component.

Comment: I understand and thank you. If you don't mind I would like to ask if you could lead me in the right direction of my next issue. I have tiles in my Panel which are actually JLabels in which I converted my characters into strings. I am able to remove certain labels using several control statements but my issue is that after one tile is removed I want the tile above it to drop down to the removed tiles previous position. I've thought of possibly adding another label to the panel when a tile is removed but I'm unsure. Thank you.

Comment: A helpful common practice is to make a "model" of what you are showing with your GUI. The model, in your case, might involve a two dimensional array, and maybe use it to hold ID numbers for your Tiles. It should ultimately be easier to inspect the array, make changes and then modify the GUI accordingly than to try and operate directly on the GUI. For example, when you take out a tile, and you have its array coordinates, it is easy to increment or decrement the Y coordinate by one to see what is above or below.